# Selenium geckodriver - WebDriverException: Reached error page:about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=https%3A//

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, geckofx, saucelabs

Still facing the same issue for geckodriver for latest selenium verison against Sauce labs.

below are my firefox capabilities.

```
    switch (browser) {
  MutableCapabilities sauceCaps = new MutableCapabilities();
case "firefox":
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", getSeleniumProperty("firefox.driver.path"));
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    sauceCaps.setCapability("seleniumVersion", "3.14.0");
    sauceCaps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, true);
    caps.setCapability("sauce:options", sauceCaps);
   }
```

logs:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=https%3A//realmhlxsumxfkayypsa1538721131324.localhost.com/db/main%3Fa%3DSignin&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20server%20at%20realmhlxsumxfkayypsa1538721131324.localhost.com%20is%20taking%20too%20long%20to%20respond.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'EC2AMAZ-F8OVLOL', ip: '10.102.180.150', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, 
browserVersion: 62.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: 
false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 2616, moz:profile: 
C:\Users\Administrator\AppD..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: 
{implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: e32ea55e-17db-47e6-8b06-1e4...}
Session ID: 4b8dd12ae8df4d118f93a4cf2d8d90a4
```

Answer (score 0):

Change permission of geckodriver And geckodriver version should be compatible to firefox version

> chmod 777 geckodriver